# How to focus on a specific instance of a class using cv2 mouse events

Tags: python, opencv, mouseevent

I'm doing a fun exercise where I draw a spline and control it using four handle points. I want to be able to drag any of the four points individually, and this works fine if I hardcode a specific state for each instance of the handle object, but I'd like to make the drag event part of the point class so I can spawn as many handles as I'd like. But now I'm at a bit of a loss because while I can get the most recently defined object to show the correct behavior, the cv2 mouse callback seems to only honor one object at a time.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np


# Lerp for handles
def lerp(start, end, dt):
    lerp_list = []
    t = 1
    while t >= 0:
        x = start[0] + (end[0] - start[0]) * t
        y = start[1] + (end[1] - start[1]) * t
        lerp_list.append([x, y])
        t = round(t-dt, 2)
    return np.int32(lerp_list)


# Lerp for spline
def lerp_spline(l1, l2):
    lerp_list = []
    for pt in range(len(l1)):
        t = pt/(len(l1)-1)
        x = l1[pt][0] + (l2[pt][0] - l1[pt][0]) * t
        y = l1[pt][1] + (l2[pt][1] - l1[pt][1]) * t
        lerp_list.append([x, y])
    return np.int32(lerp_list)


class Handle:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.dragging = False
        self.x = x + origin[0]
        self.y = y + origin[1]
        self.pt = [self.x, self.y]
        self.radius = 5

    def on_mouse_event(self, event, x, y, flags, param):
        if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
            if (x - self.x)**2 + (y - self.y)**2 < self.radius**2:
                self.dragging = True
                print("click")
        elif event == cv2.EVENT_MOUSEMOVE:
            if self.dragging:
                self.x = x
                self.y = y
                self.pt = [self.x, self.y]
                print("dragging")
        elif event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONUP:
            self.dragging = False
            print("release")


# Canvas Params
height = 512
width = 512
canvas = np.zeros((height, width, 3), dtype=np.uint8)
origin = [int(width/2), int(height/2)]

# Initial Points for Handles
radius = 5
p0 = Handle(0, -150)
p1 = Handle(-224, 200)
p2 = Handle(192, 0)
p3 = Handle(232, 192)

# Mouse events
cv2.namedWindow('Spline')
cv2.setMouseCallback('Spline', p0.on_mouse_event, param=p0)
cv2.setMouseCallback('Spline', p1.on_mouse_event, param=p1)
cv2.setMouseCallback('Spline', p2.on_mouse_event, param=p2)
cv2.setMouseCallback('Spline', p3.on_mouse_event, param=p3)

while True:
    # Wipe canvas each frame
    canvas = np.zeros((height, width, 3), dtype=np.uint8)

    # Spline Functions
    t = .05
    lp0 = lerp(p0.pt, p1.pt, t)
    lp1 = lerp(p3.pt, p2.pt, t)
    spline = lerp_spline(lp0, lp1)

    # Draw Spline
    canvas = cv2.polylines(canvas, [spline], False, (255, 255, 0), 1, lineType=cv2.LINE_AA)

    # Draw Handles
    canvas = cv2.circle(canvas, lp0[0], 2, (255, 0, 0), -1, lineType=cv2.LINE_AA)
    canvas = cv2.circle(canvas, lp1[0], 2, (255, 255, 0), -1, lineType=cv2.LINE_AA)
    canvas = cv2.circle(canvas, lp0[-1], 2, (0, 255, 255), -1, lineType=cv2.LINE_AA)
    canvas = cv2.circle(canvas, lp1[-1], 2, (0, 0, 255), -1, lineType=cv2.LINE_AA)
    canvas = cv2.line(canvas, p0.pt, p1.pt, (255, 255, 255), 1, lineType=cv2.LINE_AA)
    canvas = cv2.line(canvas, p2.pt, p3.pt, (255, 255, 255), 1, lineType=cv2.LINE_AA)

    # Show Canvas
    cv2.imshow('Spline', canvas)

    if cv2.waitKey(16) == ord('q'):
        break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Apologies for the large amount of code. It is fully operational. The part I'm concerned with is from the Handle class down.

Currently, only the most recently referenced Handle object, p3, shows correct functionality. In order to simplify the example I've repeated the mouse callback four times, once for each Handle object. Not an elegant solution but hopefully illustrates the issue.

Intention and result:
I was hoping that the Handle class might behave something like a CSS class, where the mouse event is automatically assigned to all instances of the class, and each instance performs individually. This of course was wishful thinking. What ended up happening was that only the final mouse callback seems to count. So when the script is checking if the mouse is close to self.x or self.y, it's only checking against the most recently defined coordinates.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a solution. By calling on_mouse_event() as a recursive function, it worked.

```
def on_mouse_event(event, x, y, flags, param):
    for handle in handles:
        handle.on_mouse_event(event, x, y, flags, param)
```

Then later called this function in a single mouse callback:

```
cv2.setMouseCallback('Spline', on_mouse_event)
```

Hopefully this obscure little problem will help somebody out someday :)